# Два вопроса в одном. Слово "трахнуть", а также "смена пола" говорящего.

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

1.Как вы думаете, является ли приличным говорить слово "трахнуть" в современном русском языке, если имеется в виду употребление его как синонима слова "ударить"? Например "А потом он как трахнул кулаком по столу!". Просто я вообще-то в 90% случаев слышал и читал это слово именно в смысле "иметь интимную близость". А если и встречал где-то это слово как синоним "ударить", то как правило это были очень старые книги. Поэтому ассоциации у меня с ним только неприличные.

2.Какая фраза будет более правильной? "Если бы я был девушкой, то я никогда бы не использовал косметику". "Если бы я был девушкой, то я никогда бы не ИСПОЛЬЗОВАЛА косметику". Первый вариант интуитивно кажется более правильным, зато второй вариант кажется более логичным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~1. Насчет приличий - не знаю. Это вопрос этикета, к филологии относится весьма косвенно. А по сути: глагол "трахнуть" в исходном значении никогда не относился к строго нормативным, считался то ли сугубо разговорным, то ли просторечным. Примерно таким же является и его современное эвфемистическое значение. При этом в соответствующих контекстах значения никак не путаются. 
Так что если вы в кругу друзей скажете "Я трахнул молотком по пальцу" не думаю, что кто-то вас не поймет.    
Про "очень старинные" книги - это Вы бросьте. Нынешнему значению от силы лет сорок. Это с запасом на мой возраст и круг общения после пятнадцати лет.  Но в мои школьные годы его точно не было.

~2. Первый вариант. Интуиция тут ни при чем. Дело в грамматике. В сослагательном наклонении глагол сохраняет согласование по роду.

Comment: "не думаю, что кто-то вас не поймет. ". Я тоже так думаю. Дело в восприятии. Можно сказать "Это пизд*ц" и "Это конец". Смысл одинаковый, но первый вариант звучит менее культурно. Не будет ли таже история со словом "трахнуть"?

Comment: Вообще со словом "трахнуть" странная история. В норме это эвфемизм, как и фраза "иметь интимную близость". Но сравним две фразы. "Я ее трахнул" и "Я занимался с ней сексом". Первая звучит гораздо более грубо, чем вторая. То есть получается парадокс. Эвфемизм звучит гораздо более грубо, чем непосредственно сами слова, для "маскировки" которых он и был изобретен.

Comment: *Спать*, *переспать* - это эвфемизмы. Все остальное - ненорматив.

Comment: >Вообще со словом "трахнуть" странная история.  
Вполне обычная. Посчитайте сколько раз эвфеместические названия мужского полового органа сами становились неподцензурными? 
И еще. Эвфемизм - эвфемизму рознь. Среди них тоже есть разные по степени нормативности. Но это все - к слову. 

Вы не те слова выбрали. "Маскируют"-то вполне конкретное обсценное выражение.